# How to combine dplyr::mutate() and cut to generate different factor levels in one column

Tags: r, dplyr, factors

I would like to generate different factor levels based on different categories for one column, however when I try the following:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(rap) # devtools::install_github("romainfrancois/rap")

df <- dplyr::tibble(
  category = rep(letters[1:2], each = 3),
  value = c(1, 4, 8, 21, 24, 28)
) %>% 
  tidyr::nest(data = -category) %>% 
  rap::rap(labels = ~ case_when(
    category == "a" ~ cut(data$value, c(0, 3, 6, 10), labels = c("< 3", "3 - 6", "> 6")),
    category == "b" ~ cut(data$value, c(0, 23, 26, 30), labels = c("< 23", "23 - 26", "> 26"))
  )
  )
#> Warning in `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i, value = structure(1:3, .Label = c("<
#> 23", : invalid factor level, NA generated

df
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   category           data labels   
#>   <chr>    <list<df[,1]>> <list>   
#> 1 a               [3 × 1] <fct [3]>
#> 2 b               [3 × 1] <fct [3]>
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I get `NA` for the second category of levels:

```
df %>% 
  unnest(labels)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   category value labels
#>   <chr>    <dbl> <fct> 
#> 1 a            1 < 3   
#> 2 a            4 3 - 6 
#> 3 a            8 > 6   
#> 4 b           21 <NA>  
#> 5 b           24 <NA>  
#> 6 b           28 <NA>
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can generate this different levels based on different categories?

**This is the desired output:**

```
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   category value labels
#>   <chr>    <dbl> <fct> 
#> 1 a            1 < 3   
#> 2 a            4 3 - 6 
#> 3 a            8 > 6   
#> 4 b           21 < 23  
#> 5 b           24 23 - 26  
#> 6 b           28 > 26
```

Comment: You can do `df %>%
 mutate(lable = case_when(category == "a" & value < 3 ~ "< 3",
                          category == "a" & value %in% c(3:6) ~ "3-6",
                          category == "a" & value > 6 ~ "> 6",
                          category == "b" & value < 23 ~ "< 23",
                          category == "b" & value %in% c(23:26) ~ "23-26",
                          category == "b" & value > 26 ~ "> 26",
                          TRUE ~ NA_character_))`.

Comment: that is true, but then I loose the factors

Comment: Why are you doing this with the data nested? What's the advantage / your plan with that?

Comment: because I want to preserve the factor levels on each category

Answer (score 0):

Using base R `within()`.

```
df1 <- within(df1, {
  labels[category == "a"] <- as.character(cut(value[category == "a"], 
                                              breaks=c(0, 3, 6, 10), 
                                              labels=c("< 3", "3 - 6", "> 6")))
  labels[category == "b"] <- as.character(cut(value[category == "b"], 
                                              breaks=c(0, 23, 26, 30), 
                                              labels=c("< 23", "23 - 26", "> 26")))
  labels <- as.factor(labels)
})
df1
# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#   category value labels 
#   <chr>    <dbl> <fct>  
# 1 a            1 < 3    
# 2 a            4 3 - 6  
# 3 a            8 > 6    
# 4 b           21 < 23   
# 5 b           24 23 - 26
# 6 b           28 > 26
```

#### Data

```
df1 <- structure(list(category = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"), value = c(1, 
4, 8, 21, 24, 28)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```